# Ubuntu Touch on Archos tablet?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I have an Archos 97 Carbon, and am interested in putting Ubuntu Touch on it.  I wonder if this is possible? or where to begin?

Answer (score 0):

There is a porting document at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Porting

You can also drop by in the #ubuntu-touch IRC channel on freenode.